# Will an ADSL2+ modem work with a VDSL input connection?

Tags: modem, adsl, dsl, adsl2+, vdsl

I have BT Infinity broadband (UK) which is Fibre to the Cabinet (FTTC) and then VDSL from the cabinet to the property.

BT supply a BT Openreach branded modem to work with the VDSL connection.

My question is: Will any standard ADSL2+ modem be able to handle a VDSL input if the settings are correctly adjusted?

My suspicions point me to the conclusion that the Openreach branded modem is just a basic ADSL modem (the VDSL acronym does not appear on the hardware at all, only an LED marked "DSL"), and I read that VDSL was the same technology as ADSL but with higher frequency downstream and upstream rates. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be equivalent to trying to use an ADSL modem for an ADSL2 circuit. So no, it would not work, as ADSL, ADSL2 and VDSL are all different standards on the same family of technology, DSL.

Comment: -1. I have an ADSL2+ connection, and connecting with an ASDL1 modem works just fine. (At ADSL1 speeds, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It does.

I am using D-Link 2750u modem for a VDSL connection of 16 MBPS for more than 2 years. I am getting 14.5 download speed and 1 MBPS upload speed. I am within 2 Kilometers distance from the telephone exchange.

One problem with the D-Link modem is that the firmware is not upgraded for more than 3 years.

Comment: I think that you have simply an ADSL connection, since the speeds you reported do almost perfectly match the maximum speed of ADSL. And your answer contradicts the other two.

Comment: **Sorry I might be wrong, cannot remove the downvote now**

Comment: Yes. It will work, i have vdsl fiber connection up to 100 mbps and i can use the old adsl modem but with limited speed such as 27mbps

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that this will work, unless your modem is designed to support both.

Whilst they are both digital subscriber lines, ADSL and VDSL are different standards.  See here:

http://www.broadbandlondon.com/jargon-buster/broadband-terminology-explained/