# Are modems, made for a more recent DSL standard, downwards compatible with older DSL technology?

Tags: compatibility, modem, adsl, dsl, vdsl

I understand that [older DSL modems aren't compatible with newer technology](https://superuser.com/q/216757/20634), but is the case same the other way around? I.e.:

- Is VDSL2 modem compatible with a VDSL connection? What about with ADSL or ADSL2 line?
- Is VDSL modem compatible with an ADSL/2 connection?
- Is ADSL2 modem compatible with an ADSL connection?
- Or could it be so that **2 modems* are downwards compatible only with **2 connections* (this is just guessing...)

Or is there other logic? Or are they all just incompatible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you're probably being too general - while every (ADSL2+) modem I've used has been able to choose an older mode automatically (or manually), it's probably firmware/hardware specific: even if all hardware is able to do this, firmware may have technical or even intentional (locking) restrictions against it.

Comment: Sadly your question is too broad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VDSL is not compatible in any way with ADSL.

VDSL2 capable line cards (the ISP end) are compatible with ADSL2+ ADSL2 and ADSL - so you can use these modems on a VSDL2+ connection - Its easier to find on this [juniper networks](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-security/junos-security10.1/junos-security-swconfig-interfaces-and-routing/vdsl2-interface-overview.html) document, as well as this [broadband-forum presentation](http://www.broadband-forum.org/downloads/About_DSL.pdf) - I am unclear if its possible to use a VDSL2 modem with an ADSL connection

ADSL 2+ should work with ADSL2 and ADSL in both situations

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are modems that are both ADSL2+ and VDSL2+ capable, such as the Actiontec Q1000 or the Actiontec C1000A.   The Actiontec Pk5000 originally was only ADSL2+ capable, but the current Actiontec PK5000 modems are now both ADSL2+ and VDSL2+ capable and Actiontec is working on an update to make their older P5000 modems also VDSL2+ capable.

ADSL2+ technology generally has speed capabilities of up to 20M downstream/896k upstream.  VDSL2+ is newer technology and has speed capabilities far greater, such as 40M downstream and upstream speeds of 5M, 10M or faster, instead of the standard 896k speed.   In some areas - generally major cities - there are now VDSL2+ speeds of up to 100M downstream/40M upstream available.