# Cisco 857 Integrated Services Router on vDSL line?

Tags: router, vdsl

I own a Cisco 857 router which was working on an adsl line without any problems. Lately I moved to my new home and switched my line to vdsl. The router wasn't able to sync in my new line while the router who the ISP provided me was working. Is my powerful old Cisco router to "play" to my new line with some more configuration or do I have to use the cheap one my ISP provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I use an ADSL router on a VDSL connection?

You cannot use an ADSL router on a VDSL connection (unless it is a dual ADSL/VDSL router).

An ADSL only router won't sync if the line is set to VDSL (as you found out when testing).

You **may** be able to use an ADSL modem on a **VDSL2** connection **if** the ISP has the correct kind of line card installed at the ISP end (see below).

If a router supports both ADSL and VDSL it will say so in the router specs.

The Cisco 857 spec does not say it supports VDSL:

> Cisco 850 Series: These integrated services routers support broadband cable and ADSL over analog telephone lines

Source [Cisco 857 Integrated Services Router](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/857-integrated-services-router-isr/index.html)

---

> **VDSL is not compatible in any way with ADSL.**
>
> VDSL2 capable line cards (the ISP end) are compatible with ADSL2+
>   ADSL2 and ADSL - so you can use these modems on a VSDL2+ connection -
>   it's easier to find on this [juniper networks document](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-security/junos-security10.1/junos-security-swconfig-interfaces-and-routing/vdsl2-interface-overview.html), as well as this
>   [broadband-forum presentation](http://www.broadband-forum.org/downloads/About_DSL.pdf).
>
> ADSL 2+ should work with ADSL2 and ADSL in both situations

Source: Answer to [Are modems, made for a more recent DSL standard, downwards compatible with older DSL technology?](https://superuser.com/questions/392647/are-modems-made-for-a-more-recent-dsl-standard-downwards-compatible-with-older) by [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek)

---

#### Can I use a VDSL2 Modem on an ADSL connection?

You can normally use a VDSL2 modem on an ADSL connection, as they usually support ADSL2 and ADSL2+ as well as VDSL2.

Comment: I think that this router is a bit old and the info are outdated. Maybe vdsl lines wasn't exists back then. I tried another cheap adsl2 router and worked without any configuration. Maybe i have to change something in my cisco router config or its just different technologies?

Comment: @Alexandros The technologies are different. What was the other router you tried?

Comment: The old router was the Thomson TG585

Comment: The Thomson TG585 supports ADSL2+. Perhaps that makes a difference...

Comment: @Alexandros Answer updated with some more info.