# Can I use the TP-LINK TD-W8960N (ADSL2+) as VDSL modem

Tags: wireless-networking, modem, adsl, vdsl

I want to find out can I use the below modem ([TP-LINK TD-W8960N ADSL modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0031SUB4S)) as VDSL mode, so I have seen this post which the [Rao](https://superuser.com/users/651264/rao) said :

[Will an ADSL2+ modem work with a VDSL input connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/216757/will-an-adsl2-modem-work-with-a-vdsl-input-connection)

> Yes. It does.
>
> I am using D-Link 2750u modem for a VDSL connection of 16 MBPS for
> more than 2 years. I am getting 14.5 download speed and 1 MBPS upload
> speed. I am within 2 Kilometers distance from the telephone exchange.

And the TP-LINK TD-W8960N (ADSL2+)has had 10 Mb/s upload, 100/s Mb download speed as you can see below:

[image: webpage]

I know the VDSL speed is above 50Mb/s and using `the TP-LINK TD-W8960N  ADSL2+ modem` with around 100Mb/s speed, is ok for us.

So, if possible, I like to have some comment about can I use the `TP-LINK TD-W8960N` modem as VDSL modem?

Comment: You provided a link to the product in question, but apparently you didn't read all of it.  About a third-way down the page, under "Product description" and "Compatible ISPs", there's the explicit declaration of  ***"Not compatible with VDSL service"***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TD-W8960N is *only* an ADSL modem – it literally does not have the hardware that could understand or generate VDSL signals.

Many ISPs provide "VDSL" connections that actually [support both](https://superuser.com/a/393888) VDSL and ADSL modems, so the TD-W8960N should still *work* with such a connection – but only in ADSL2+ mode and ADSL2+ speeds.